# What is the difference between EDE and EDE3?

Tags: algorithm, des

I was going through the OpenSSL cipher algorithms list. I found these two:

```
des-ede-cbc
des-ede3-ofb
```

What does that exactly mean? What is the difference between EDE and EDE3? What are the key-size and blocksize of the algorithms?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27580751/does-des-ede3-mean-the-same-as-triple-des

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/enc.html and found the following:

```
des-ede-cbc        Two key triple DES EDE in CBC mode
des-ede3-ofb       Three key triple DES EDE in OFB mode
```

So, EDE is two-key triple DES, and EDE3 is three-key triple DES.  See https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/63449/what-is-the-keyspace-of-2-key-3des for the differences between two-key triple DES and three-key triple DES.